# Load essential styles to shadow-dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I love the idea of shadow dom styles encapsulation, but I'd like to include base styles to each shadow dom (reset, typography, etc).

```
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css">
 ...
 </head>

 <my-component></my-component>
 <script>
   
   customElements.define('my-component', class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
     ...
     connectedCallback() {
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
        linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'core.css');

        // applying exiting "core.css" to current shadow dom 
        this.shadow.appendChild(linkElem);
    }
   });
 </script>
```

Since `core.css` was called (linked) twice will it affect the performance?

Answer (score 3):

You could try use [Constructable Stylesheet Objects](https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md#constructable-stylesheet-objects)

With this approach you can define global styles and then use them with `shadowRoot.adoptedStylesheets` like the following:

```
import {
    resetSheet,
    headlinesSheet,
    coreSheet,
} from '/style-system.js';
import {
    myComponentStyles,
} from './styles.js';

// ...

    connectedCallback() {
        // Only compose styles once
        if (!this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets.length) {
            this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheet = [
                // global stylesheets
                resetSheet,
                headlinesSheet,
                coreSheet,
                // specific sheet for this component
                myComponentStyles
            ]
        }
    }
```

The main advantages with this approach in comparison with the one you're using (creating link elements to each component) are:

- You can share global styles to be used across multiple components defining them once
- You only load the styles being used by that component being rendered and this scales performance because it lazily loads stylesheets
- You can change those global styles dynamically (as they're a JS component) without the need of applying changes in multiple elements, making more decoupled changes

As this is a quite new approach, I'd recommend you read the following articles in order to create a more solid knowledge about `Constructable Stylesheet Objects`

1. [Constructible Stylesheets](https://css-tricks.com/encapsulating-style-and-structure-with-shadow-dom/#constructible-stylesheets)
2. [Why Would Anyone Use Constructible Stylesheets, Anyways?](https://dev.to/westbrook/why-would-anyone-use-constructible-stylesheets-anyways-19ng)
3. [Adopt a Design System inside your Web Components with Constructable Stylesheets](https://medium.com/swlh/adopt-a-design-system-inside-your-web-components-with-constructable-stylesheets-dd24649261e)

Comment: Great! But it's only supported in chrome right now :( https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_document_adoptedstylesheets

Comment: Hmm that's a shame, sorry didn't know that, though something really cool to be looking for in the next few weeks/months. Good luck on this, buddy

Comment: Link the css file from each component. If you do run into performance issues you most likely have many other problems. Constructed stylesheets are a future solution

Answer (score 0):

The browser will cache the request for `core.css` so there's not really a performance penalty, but since the stylesheet will be loaded asynchronously you might get a flash of unstyled content (FOUC) while the browser fetches the css for the first time.

One possible way to get around this is to preload the css file in your document `<head>`, so that it will (probably, as preloads are only 'hints' to the browser) be available by the time your Shadow DOM is parsed:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="core.css" as="style">
```